# comparison within in clause of postgresql

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, where-in, clause, subquery

Is it possible to add condition within the in clause of postgresql

for example

```
select ... where (t1.subject,t2.weight) in ((1,2),(2,3))
```

I want to check whether subject is 1 but weight can be >= 2 not just 2 and so on. So that condition would logically look somewhat like

```
select ... where (t1.subject,t2.weight) in ((1,>2),(2,>3))
```

Comment: Meaningless code does not communicate to others what you wish it meant. Also "like" & "somewhat" do not explain "is". And "logically" doesn't mean anything in particular. Please: Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help] Show what you are able to do. Research before considering asking & reflect research in a question. [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You need to write

```
…
WHERE t1.subject = 1 AND t2.weight > 2
   OR t1.subject = 2 AND t2.weight > 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select value of object using subquery. Simple just select query subject which are having weight greater than >=2.

select ... where (t1.subject,t2.weight) in (select subject FROM ... where weight >=2 ,select subject FROM ... where weight >=3 );